# How to design a versionable and publishable entity?

Tags: database-design, relational-theory

I have encountered this problem a couple times. I have an entity that has versions and only one of those versions is the published version. As an example, let's say we have the entities **Book** and **Book Version**. I thought about a couple of approaches to this problem.

1.
We have 2 tables.

**Book**

| Column | Type |
| --- | --- |
| id | int |
| name | varchar |

**Book Version**

| Column | Type |
| --- | --- |
| id | int |
| book_id | fk |
| published | boolean |
| created_at | date |

In this case there has to be a constraint in published to allow only one unique true value for a certain book.

2.
Again, we have 2 tables but we change the published column.

**Book**

| Column | Type |
| --- | --- |
| id | int |
| name | varchar |
| book_id (published version) | fk |

**Book Version**

| Column | Type |
| --- | --- |
| id | int |
| book_id | fk |
| created_at | date |

This time the Book table has a FK to the published version.

3.
We add a third table with that will have the published information.

**Book**

| Column | Type |
| --- | --- |
| id | int |
| name | varchar |

**Book Version**

| Column | Type |
| --- | --- |
| id | int |
| book_id | fk |
| created_at | date |

**Published Book Version**

| Column | Type |
| --- | --- |
| book_id | fk |
| bookversion_id | fk |

Now we added a third table with a unique constraint on book_id to allow only one published version per book.

Which option do you think is best? Is there a better approach i haven't mentioned? Is there an accepted solution to this design problem?

- My problem with 1 is that we will end up with a bunch of false values in the published column.
- My problem with 2 and 3 is that we could end up with an inconsistent database if we reference a BookVersion that does not belong to that particular Book.

Comment: What are we actually talking about with `Book` and are the versions just older versions of the entity or drafts?  Provide some business context around how/when a `Book` is published.

Comment: @bbaird Yes. A user will have a Book and upload different versions (we can consider them drafts). The user can see the older versions but they cannot edit them. There can only be one published version of a Book at a given time but it doesn't need to be the last one. Other users will only be able to see the published version.

Comment: The first thing I would at this point is drop the `id` columns and then try laying out your keys that way.  I'd also challenge you to think about how to structure the flow, have one `Book` with a flag `PublishedInd` or `IsPublished`.  Whenever there is an edit, the old version goes to an entity `BookVersion` with the timestamp of the change added to the primary key.  When a `Book` is published, you set the flag to true.  Try that approach and then update your question if you're still stuck.